# what is the noun and verb which mean "to hold yourself back"

Tags: vocabulary

I'll give an example:

I can't stand him anymore = There's a limit to my _____(noun)____

And if there is a verb which equal to "can't stand (sth) anymore", I'd also like to learn.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"There's a limit to my **restraint**"

"There's a limit to my **patience**"

Or, simply the noun "limit" can have this meaning in context, e.g.:

"I have my **limits**".

There are also variations of an idiomatic expression: "I'm at the end of my tether" meaning you are at the end of your patience with a situation or person.

Comment: Also, "end of my rope". This may be an AmE/BrE split.

Answer (score 4):

There's a limit to my tolerance.

Comment: I especially like this one used as a verb" *I can't **tolerate** him anymore* (to answer the last part of the OP's request).

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit to my **forbearance**.

Not especially idiomatic in the modern world, at least in my experience.  This choice has a certain ... maybe "haughtiness" to it.  Like if you were invoking the idea of someone in a position of power, this could help convey that sense.

Answer (score -4):

A word that is both noun and verb that means "to hold yourself back is: "Retard." However, you should be very careful about how you are using this word as, "Retard" also is an insulting way of referring to someone of limited mental abilities.  As in, "calling someone a retard."  You can correctly refer to a brake "retarding" the motion of a wheel, but due to the problematic nature of this word, most people seek to use other related descriptive terms.

Comment: "Retard" doesn't mean "hold yourself back"; it means "slow yourself down". Furthermore, "retard" is rarely anymore, due partly to its association with low mental ability.

Comment: @200_success Should I speak of the timing on my car's ignition being "chronologically privileged or chronologically challenged"?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany No, the spark is usually said to be either "early" or "late".

Comment: @200_success  I have heard nothing but "advanced" and "retarded" in that context.

Comment: Answer doesn't fit the example sentence.